# How to write a hook to decrypt data on query with Prisma ORM

Tags: javascript, encryption, prisma, fastify

`Basic information first`: API built with [`Fastify`](https://www.fastify.io/) framework, using [`Prisma`](https://www.prisma.io/) ORM to handle crud operations with a `Postgres` database.

`The problem`: I have to encrypt a couple of fields before storing it on the database. Fields are: the User's `Name` and `Email`. Encryption is achieved through the [`crypto-js`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) library. Encrypting data before storing it is easy. My problem lies when using encrypted data in queries, like, selecting users with an email. Email is encrypted. You can see how it wouldn't work as a where condition, since every time I encrypt the same value it produces a different encrypted value. If it mathers, the encryption type is `AES`.

Below you can find the code responsible for the login endpoint, as you can see, it searches for users with X email and if it finds the user it compares it's password to validate credentials. It works fine with non-encrypted emails, but when I apply encryption to the values stored, no more login.

```js
fastify.post(
    "/login",
    {
      schema: {
        description: "This is an endpoint to handle user login",
        tags: ["user", "login"],
        body: {
          type: "object",
          additionalProperties: false,
          required: ["email", "password"],
          properties: {
            email: { type: "string" },
            password: { type: "string" },
          },
        },
        response: {
          200: {
            description: "Login successful",
            type: "object",
            properties: {
              token: { type: "string" },
            },
          },
          204: {
            description: "No user found",
            properties: {},
          },
        },
      },
    },
    async (request, reply) => {
      let credentials = {
        email: request.body.email,
      };

      const prisma = new PrismaClient();

      try {
        const user = await prisma.users.findFirst({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!user) {
          reply.code(204);
          return;
        }

        const match = await fastify.bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        );

        if (!match) {
          reply.code(204);
          return;
        }

        const token = fastify.jwt.sign(
          { email: user.email, password: user.password },
          { expiresIn: "12h" }
        );

        reply.code(200);
        return { token };
      } finally {
        prisma.$disconnect();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

`What am I trying to achieve`: As far as I know, I need to be able to implement a hook on Prisma's query to decrypt emails to be able to compare them with the supplied email in the where condition, question is, how? I tried using Prisma's Middlewares but either I'm dumb and dind't manage to get it working or it is the wrong approach to it. Anyone has any idea on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: I suppose you would have tried using Prisma Middleware with the `prisma.$use` API, they have the option of performing an operation before invoking a query, that would be the ideal place to perform the decrypt operation. Did you run into any errors while trying it out? Reference: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware

Comment: @NurulSundarani yes, I did try to use middlewares, but I didn't see how I could decrypt the information received by the query since my where condition already screws up the select operation. Since I'm using AES encryption on emails, everytime I encrypt that information it produces a different value... I'd have to select all users and then compare on the server (which is not the best approach). I honestly don't know how to middlewares could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first I thing I would do is evaluate the reason you need to encrypt, and determine if [data at rest encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-data-encryption.html) or similar would satisfy the requirements.  Assuming for whatever reason it does not, then what I would try is adding a column for `hashed_email`.  Then you salt + hash the email using something like SHA-3, and then you can use the hashed_email column for querying, and once you have the row, can decrypt the email if you need to.

Otherwise, I don't see a way to do it aside from loading every single user, and checking each one to see if the login matches, which obviously wouldn't scale.

Comment: I'll take a look into your suggestion, if it works out, I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks for the input tho, I hadn't thought about it.

Comment: I implemented the solution you provided, if anyone has any alternatives, I'm all ears. But thanks for the suggestion, I really appreciated it.